# focal InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'focal-updates' to 'focal-security'

Tags: apt, 20.04, ppa, inkscape

When I tried `sudo apt update` in 20.04 through Terminal, I am stuck at this

```
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'focal-updates' to 'focal-security'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to simply press <kbd>y</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> answering the prompt in your question.

Or re-add this repository with commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:inkscape.dev/stable

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
```

And then use this repository as before.

Comment: Thanks. So there is nothing malicious in it, right ?

Comment: Seems to be distro/meta-data change, so nothing malicious.